# How to write input code on several lines

Tags: formatting

In *Mathematica*, how can I write input code on several lines?

My version of *Mathematica* (10.2) on my computer (Windows 8) PC using Google Chrome evaluates at Enter instead of Shift+Enter. (Thanks to Bill Simpson and Sarah Adams for understanding on what was happening.) Everyone else writes code, clicks Enter and the cursor moves down to the next line.  Every time I click Enter, the program evaluates what I have written.

I have restarted *Mathematica* holding down the Control+Shift keys. 
I have restored defaults everywhere available in Edit -> Preferences.

When I open a new notebook, I click on Evaluation -> Quit Kernel -> Local.
When the cursor is sideways, Evaluation-Evaluate Cells-Shift+Enter is grayed out.

If I click on the + and Choose How to Enter Input -> Wolfram Language, sometimes it will allow me to click on Enter without evaluating, but not all the time.

Well, I am going to try this in another browser. How does *Mathematica* like Firefox?

Any assistance would be appreciated.

Comment: The `Enter` key? Perhaps you should read some of the introductory Mathematica documentation. Start [here](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/UsingANotebookInterface.html).

Comment: If Mathematica can clearly tell there is "more stuff coming", like perhaps {1,2, ..useEnterKeyHere.. 3,4} or even things like (x=4; y=2; ..UseEnterKeyHere.. z=3) then it almost always understands you meant to have several items and the EnterKey was just formatting. BUT when using the EnterKey with no trailing comma, semicolon, parens, braces, etc. there has been a long history of Mathematica misunderstanding Enter or Space as meaning you wanted those two things multiplied together and this can cause really hard to find bugs unless you watch out for this.

Comment: I am sure this is a trivial question, but I am near tears trying to figure it out. I have read and googled and read again the documentation.  There must be something simple I am not seeing.  Rather than put me [ON HOLD] would someone have mercy and show me how?  I used the Enter Key to go down but Mathematica sees this as different input.

Comment: Can you give us an example of something that you tried, or something specific that you are trying to do? It is actually hard to help with your specific problem without knowing what you are actually doing.

Comment: Something as simple as x=3 enter y=4 enter z=3.                                At the enter, Mathematica evaluates every time.                                           What I am trying to do is write code like Manipulate[Plot[[(a*x^2 + b*x + c), {x, -10, 10}, PlotRange -> {-20, 20},   PlotLabel ->    Row[{"Discriminant = ", b^2 - 4*a*c}]],....  neatly by writing the input over several lines where I choose the line breaks.

Comment: @GwenVastine Once upon a time, computers had both "Return" and "Enter" keys.  The "Enter" was equivalent to "Shift-Return", and would evaluate the input.  "Return" by itself would enter a newline.  Perhaps you have such a keyboard?  (I haven't had one for years and cannot test it.) -- P.S. Use @ + username to guarantee that the user will be notified of your response.

Comment: You mention "... using Google Chrome". Are you using _Mathematica_ Online? Most of comments seem to assume you are interfacing to _Mathematica_ through a local notebook front-end, and if that's a wrong assumption, it would account for the confusion.

Comment: @m_Goldberg I noticed that too, but Gwen writes "I have restarted Mathematica holding down the Control+Shit keys. I have restored defaults everywhere available in Edit -> Preferences." This does not sound like Mathematica Online.

Comment: @gwen you state that you use "enter" to get a new line, but you should use the "return" key for that. The former usually sits on the numerical key pad section of the keyboard. The latter is the key on the right end of the main part of a (long) keyboard.

Comment: @gwen You are talking about Chrome and FireFox, which suggest you are using Mathematica Online or the Programming Cloud (web-based versions of Mathematica). However, you also mention menu items that are not present there and that are only available in the desktop version. So, what system are you actually working on?

Comment: I knew the answer had to be something very elemental.  I thought the Enter at the right of the alphabet was the same as the Enter at the right of the numbers.  For everything else, that has proved to be the case.